# set entire DataRow with 1 line

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm setting a DataRow's value like the following

```
mydatarow[0] = "h"
mydatarow[1] = "but"
```

How to do something like this

```
mydatarow = {"h", "but"}
```

Comment: hi, perhaps, `row = dt.NewRow(); row.ItemArray = new object[] {"h", "but"}; dt.Rows.Add(row);`

Comment: @IronMan Much shorter: `dt.Rows.Add("h", "but");`